# r data.table impute missing values for multiple set of columns

Tags: r, function, data.table, missing-data, imputation

I want to impute missing values for few set of columns. The idea is for numeric variables I want to use the **median** to impute the `NA` and for categorical variables I want to use the **mode** to impute the `NA`. I did search for how to impute it separately for different set of columns and did not find.

My data is big with many columns so I have it in **data.table**. Since I am not sure how to do it in data.table, I tried below code base R. I have tried below code but somehow I am messing up with the column name identification it seems.

My data is large and with multiple variables. I am storing numeric variables in vector **var_num** and I am storing categorical variables in vector **var_chr**.

Please see my sample code below -

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1200)
id <- 1:100
bills <- sample(c(1:20,NA),100,replace = T)
nos <- sample(c(1:80,NA),100,replace = T)
stru <- sample(c("A","B","C","D",NA),100,replace = T)
type <- sample(c(1:7,NA),100,replace = T)
value <- sample(c(100:1000,NA),100,replace = T)

df1 <- as.data.table(data.frame(id,bills,nos,stru,type,value))
class(df1)

var_num <- c("bills","nos","value")
var_chr <- c("stru","type")

impute <- function(x){
  #print(x)
  if(colnames(x) %in% var_num){
    x[is.na(x)] = median(x,na.rm = T)
  } else if (colnames(x) %in% var_chr){
    x[is.na(x)] = mode(x)
  } else {
    x #if not part of var_num and var_chr then nothing needs to be done and return the original value
  }
  return(x)
}


df1_imp_med <- data.frame(apply(df1,2,impute))
```

When I try to run the above it gives me error `Error in if (colnames(x) %in% var_num) { : argument is of length zero`

Please help me understand how I can correct this and achieve my requirement.

Comment: If you're using `data.table` you should consider taking advantage of its capabilites like update-by-reference using `:=` assingment, or in this case possibly better suited, `for` + `set` to iterate over several columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you can use `for-set` combination in data.table for a faster imputation:

```
for(k in names(df1)){

      if(k %in% var_num){

        # impute numeric variables with median
        med <- median(df1[[k]],na.rm = T)
        set(x = df1, which(is.na(df1[[k]])), k, med)

    } else if(k %in% var_char){

        ## impute categorical variables with mode
        mode <- names(which.max(table(df1[[k]])))
        set(x = df1, which(is.na(df1[[k]])), k, mode)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want to refer to the variables specified in var_num and var_chr.....you solution would do the imputation for all columns. But yes, it will be a good reference.

Comment: And here's the general solution I couldn't immediately come up with ;) Note for OP, with this method the "type" column of `df1` needs to be changed to a factor or character to calculate the mode instead of median (as it is a numeric vector, but mode is desired)

Comment: @user1412 I made it more generic previously such that you don't need to hardcode the column names, just updated the answer.

Comment: @YOLO Thank you !!

Answer (score 3):

It may or may not be worth your time coding up a single function for both of your use cases. A direct (but specific) solution is below -- note that `mode` may not be behaving as you expect, by reading `?mode`.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1200)
df1 <- data.table(
id = 1:100,
bills = sample(c(1:20,NA),100,replace = T),
nos = sample(c(1:80,NA),100,replace = T),
stru = sample(c("A","B","C","D",NA),100,replace = T),
type = sample(c(as.character(1:7),NA),100,replace = T),
value = sample(c(100:1000,NA),100,replace = T)
)

# Function to calculate the most frequent object in a vector:
getMode <- function(myvector) {
    mytable <- table(myvector)
    return(names(mytable)[which.max(mytable)])
}

# replace na values by reference, with `:=`
df1[is.na(bills), bills := median(df1[,bills], na.rm=T)]
df1[is.na(nos), nos := median(df1[,nos], na.rm=T)]
df1[is.na(value), value := median(df1[,value], na.rm=T)]
df1[is.na(stru), stru := getMode(df1[,stru])]
df1[is.na(type), type := getMode(df1[,type])]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I got that mode is different in R and using the combination of names(which(table....see my answer. As you mentioned this would be a lengthy way of doing it as there are many variables....

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a working solution. One of the key things was to refer to the variables specified in **var_num** and **var_chr** for numeric and categorical imputation. Variables that are not specified in these vectors need not be imputed.

Challenge I was facing is to refer to them in the function. I dropped the idea of writing the function and managed to write a **for loop** as below -

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

for (var in 1:ncol(df1)) {
  if (names(df1[var]) %in% var_num) {
    df1[is.na(df1[,var]),var] <- median(df1[,var], na.rm = TRUE)
  } else if (names(df1[var]) %in% var_chr) {
    df1[is.na(df1[,var]),var] <- names(which.max(table(df1[,var])))
  }
}
```

This **for loop** does the needed imputation.

If there is more **simpler** and **concise** way of achieving this do let me know. Maybe some apply family may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `lapply`

```
lapply(c(var_num, var_chr), function(x){ 
  imp.fun <- ifelse(x %in% var_num
                   , function(x) median(x, na.rm = T) 
                   , function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))
  df1[is.na(df1[[x]]), (x) := imp.fun(df1[[x]])]})
```

Comment: That code doesn't run, but there's the similar `imp = df1[, c(lapply(.SD[, ..var_num], median, na.rm = TRUE), lapply(.SD[, ..var_chr], getMode))]; for (k in c(var_num, var_chr)) df1[is.na(get(k)), (k) := imp[[k]]][]` (getMode borrowed from caw's answer)